# Does Apple make any notebooks with matte display?

Tags: macbook

I love to work outdoors, so I prefer matte displays over glossy. Does apple have any laptop model which has matte screen? I have seen only glossy variants until now.

Comment: I presume not, since there seems to be a market for anti-glare screen protectors for macbooks - would that be an acceptable resolution?

Comment: Hi @JeffZeitlin, thanks for response. What do you mean, "would that be an acceptable resolution"? What resolution?

Comment: Aha, you meant solution, I thouht you are talking about pixels or DPI :-D Well, I know of this option, I try to avoid this, because of the problematic installation, bubbles etc.... it's much better if it's already made matte.

Comment: Always good to have a screen protector anyway, so you have a win win by having a) matte and b) a protected screen. Just get a decent quality one, give the screen a jolly good clean first and take your time with the application of the protector.

Comment: Thanks @spikey_richie. Is there any service where they would apply it? It would make sense, given how demanding the application is.